# best way to handle prebuild and post build events while making a setup

Tags: installation, prebuild

hi i have many prebuild and postbuild events in different projects.

i want to write these events in a single batch file and then call this script in the main 
project please tell me this is the correct way or any other best way of handlling these events while making a setup

thanks

please tell me how to handle prebuild and postbuild events in different projects with in the same soluntion from msbuild.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Something like [Nant](http://nant.sf.net) and/or [MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k6kkbsd.aspx) would be the way to go here, much more robust than a batch file due to inbuilt error handling, logging, etc.